# Implementing word counter

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I am implementing a word counter. For every occurrence of a work I create a counter if none already exists and if it already exists I increase its counter value.
I was just going to use a HashMap and then store an Integer as the value and increase that. I just want to make sure there is not some fancy class out there that would simplify this even further?

Thanks.

Comment: Map is good choice for this purpose.

Comment: Rather than using an immutable Integer as the value, I create my own mutable Counter class that supports increment() and getValue().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use common 3rd party libraries, a [`HashBag`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/HashBag.html) would take care of all of this. Note that the APIs reveal an underlying [`MutableInteger`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/AbstractMapBag.MutableInteger.html) that is a telltale sign that its doing what you'd be doing yourself.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
Iterable<String> words = ...;
Bag<String> counts = new HashBag<String>();
for (String word : words) {
  counts.add(word);
}
for (String word : counts.uniqueSet()) {
  int count = counts.getCount(word);
  System.out.println(word + "\t" + count);
}
```